# installing gapfiller-2.1.1

Tags: compiling

Hello all I am trying to compile gapfiller-2.1.1. 
Following the readme file to

```
$ ./configure
```

it runs and gets the error:

```
configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.40.0
```

Make does not work. Looking through the posts I try the following:

```
$ ./configure LIBS="-lz" 
$ ./configure
```

Error:

```
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate 
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.40.0... no 
configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.40.0
```

more posts try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Still error. Try:

```
$ ./autoconfig 
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev 
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

get a new error:

```
checking for Boost headers version >= 1.40.0... yes 
checking for Boost's header version...  
configure: error: invalid value: boost_major_version=
```

looking through other posts I try:

```
$ cat configure | grep "boost_cv_lib_version="
```

get:

```
boost_cv_lib_version=`cat conftest.i`
```

then try:

```
$ dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
```

get:

```
Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
```

I’m guessing I need to change the boost_major_version to this in the compile code?

```
fi 
{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $boost_cv_lib_version" >&5 
$as_echo "$boost_cv_lib_version" >&6; } 
    # e.g. "134" for 1_34_1 or "135" for 1_35 
    boost_major_version=`echo "$boost_cv_lib_version" | sed 's/_//;s/_.*//'` 
    case $boost_major_version in #( 
      '' | *[!0-9]*) 
        as_fn_error $? "invalid value: boost_major_version=$boost_major_version" "$LINENO" 5 
        ;; 
    esac 
fi
```

but not sure how? 
Does this sound right? 
Any suggestions?